# Using JDK outside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java

Eclipse is said to have an inbuilt jdk, can we use it outside eclipse for simple javac eg through command prompt?

I may be wrong in assumptions please guide on that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has an inbuilt Incremental Java Compiler not a full JDK as far as I know.

More information can be found in the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm) and the [JDT core page](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php#DEV)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are referring to the built-in compiler in Eclipse.  Different ways to use this  is documented [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm)

Comment: +1 Eclipse doesn't have a JDK built in, but it does have a compiler.

Comment: so can i use it to run a compile task in ant ??